# How can I do asynchronous download of sites of using Transmit's Automator action?

Tags: automator, data-transfer, ftp

I want to take backup of my sites regularly, so I setup Automator with Transmit. I also used Calendar to trigger the downloads on schedule.

The problem is how can I tell Automator to download sites one at a time, rather than opening number of transmit copies.

At the moment I use "Pause", but would be more accurate to know if one download is completed then launch the next download.

Comment: How are you telling Automator to download the sites?

Comment: Automator > application > type download then it will show you the "Transmit" icon. from there you can pickup the site you want to download and set the remote and local path.